# SetImageResources using View Binding

Tags: android-viewbinding

I try to bind my ImageView using the setImageResource but i got type mismatch error can someone help me please.

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RobotViewHolder, position: Int) {

```
    val currentItem = robotList[position]

    with(holder.binding) {

        robotItemImageView.setImageResource = currentItem.imageResource
        categoryNameTextView.text = currentItem.text1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,

```
    with(holder.binding) {
        robotItemImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageResource)
        categoryNameTextView.text = currentItem.text1
    }
```